# Creating files using redirection

Tags: command-line, redirect, tree

I have a task to do for my homework so please help me.
I am in a parent directory which itself has 2 directories (let s name them A and B).
In this parent directory I have to create a file in B which has the tree of A.
i thought i can do something like this:
tree -a /A >> file /b
but it s not good.
Can you help me, please??

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not good"? Why is it not good?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the requirements, but I would perhaps look at the find and cpio commands.

The find command can give you a listing of all files, just directories, etc.
And using the pipe (|) or redirection (>) you can either make a copy of the contents of a directory (eg. with cpio command) or just a file containing the list of contents of a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Understand the difference between absolute and relative paths -- absolute starts with a / from the top of the filesystem, and relative starts from where your current working directory (default when no path is specified) is set to. The command pwd prints your current working directory, and cwd changes it. files are specified as path/file, so your command is:

```
 tree -a A > B/file
```

(or >> to append to the file).